# int function error in lazy fold_right definition

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I'm trying to write a modified version of `Batteries.LazyList.lazy_fold_right`.  I want a similar function that folds on two lazy lists rather than one lazy list.  However, I'm getting an error that doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is the original Batteries definition I started from, in [batLazyList.ml](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batLazyList.ml#L147):

```
let lazy_fold_right f l init =
  let rec aux rest = lazy begin
    match next rest with
    | Cons (x, t) -> f x (aux t)
    | Nil -> Lazy.force init
  end in
aux l
```

Here's my version:

```
let lazy_fold_right2 f l1 l2 init =
  let open Batteries.LazyList in
  let rec aux rest1 rest2 =
    lazy begin
      match next rest1, next rest2 with
      | Cons (x1, t1), Cons (x2, t2) -> f x1 x2 (aux t1 t2)
      | Nil, Nil | Nil, _ | _, Nil -> Lazy.force init
    end
  in
aux l1 l2
```

The error is on the variable `init` at the end of the line with multiple `Nil`s:

`Error: This expression has type int -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a t but an expression was expected of type 'b lazy_t`

Huh?  Where is there anything related to `int`s in the code?  What am I not seeing?

(`Cons`, `Nil`, and `next` are all defined for `LazyList` in batLazyList.ml.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the `init` function in `Batteries.LazyList` that shadows the local `init` variable. Two possibilities to avoid the problem are either to activate the warning 44 (for shadowed local identifiers) or define a short alias for `Batteries.LazyList` rather than a local open:

```
let lazy_fold_right2 f l1 l2 init =
  let module L = Batteries.LazyList in
  let rec aux rest1 rest2 =
    lazy begin
      match L.next rest1, L.next rest2 with
      | L.Cons (x1, t1), Cons (x2, t2) -> f x1 x2 (aux t1 t2)
      | Nil, Nil | Nil, _ | _, Nil -> Lazy.force init
    end
  in
aux l1 l2
```

Comment: Thanks octachron!  I normally use the alias method throughout a source file, but in this case there were so many identifiers I thought it would be easier to use a local `open`.  I forgot about the danger of shadowing.  I might just rename `init`, though, in this case.  I'm not wedded to it.